# How to connect two android apps to the same database so that I can pass information between them?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two apps. One which is a text to speech converter. The text that is being converted to speech is stored into the database dynamically. Now, I want another app to be able to access this data. Is there any way the second app can share the database with the first one. I am using SQLite.

Comment: you can use [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider)

Comment: Yes! contentProvider

Answer (score 1):

You can do either of the following:

1. Use content providers
2. Create a server database using mysql, sql server or other db
3. Use Firebase to connect your apps with cloud database.